# Как в 1С правильно соединять поля?

Tags: 1с

Есть:

`Документы-ИнвентаризацияОС-НомерДокумента`,

`Документы-ИнвентаризацияОС-ПодраздлениеОрганизации`,

`Документы-ИнвентаризацияОС-ОС-ОсновноеСредство` (табличная часть, где находится название ОС),

`РегистрСведений.ДополнительныеСведения.Объект` (где тоже находится название ОС),

`Справочник.ОсновныеСредства.Наименование`,

```
Справочник.ОсновныеСредства.Код
```

У `Документы-ИнвентаризацияОС-ОС-ОсновноеСредство` и `РегистрСведений.ДополнительныеСведения.Объект` общее это название ОС.

Как их правильно объединить? Здесь получается так, что значения полей Справочник.ОсновныеСредства.Код уникальны, а у остальных полей повторяющиеся.

Пробовал писать такой код, но там выводятся похожие поля:

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
    ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.Номер КАК Номер,
    ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.ПодразделениеОрганизации КАК ПодразделениеОрганизации,
    ИнвентаризацияОС.ОсновноеСредство,
    ОсновныеСредства.Код КАК Код,
    ДополнительныеСведения.Объект КАК Объект,
    ДополнительныеСведения.Значение КАК Значение
ИЗ
    Справочник.ОсновныеСредства КАК ОсновныеСредства,
    РегистрСведений.ДополнительныеСведения КАК ДополнительныеСведения
        ВНУТРЕННЕЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ОС КАК ИнвентаризацияОС
        ПО ДополнительныеСведения.Объект = ИнвентаризацияОС.ОсновноеСредство"
 ГДЕ ДополнительныеСведения.Значение=&Значение";
```

Comment: Приведите Ваш вывод и каким хотите видеть

Comment: @MaxDown
задача в том, что нужно готовить такой список (таблицу):
`Код | Номер | Название ОС | Значение дополнительного сведения`
Проблема в том, что `Код` находится в справочнике, `Номер` находится в документах, `Значение дополнительного сведения` находится в регистре сведений.

Comment: Всё никак не победите эту свою проблему...

Comment: Можете копию базы или хотя бы конфигурации прислать?

Answer (score 1):

Когда в запросе используется условие для соединения

```
ВНУТРЕННЕЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ОС КАК ИнвентаризацияОС
        ПО ДополнительныеСведения.Объект = ИнвентаризацияОС.ОсновноеСредство
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
ВНУТРЕННЕЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ОС КАК ИнвентаризацияОС
        ПО Таблица1.Поле1 = Таблица2.Поле2
```

Необходимо чтобы `Поле1` и `Поле2` были **ОДИНАКОВОГО ТИПА** Чтобы в этом убедиться, *в конфигураторе* находим `Таблица1` реквизит `Поле1` *Свойства* и смотрим **ТИП**, также смотрим **ТИП** у `Поле2`;

Если `Поле2` составного типа, открываем список и смотрим указан ли галочкой **ТИП** как у `Поле1`;